# keys on the keyboard are not working sometimes

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

Some keys on the keyboard such as: "g" "h" "left alt" "esc" "up arrow" are not working full time.

However, after pressing some other keys ("s" "a" "d" and on) they start working all of them at once.

Do you guys know what it could be?

Comment: Maybe a bad keyboard?

Comment: I have tried with a different keyboard and similar problem

Comment: Is this a desktop computer? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: 90 percent of the time this kind of problem come from the hardware, either had keyboard, bad cable, bad plug, bad socket, or bad keyboard controller chip in the motherboard. This has been my experience with keyboards.